# MonoGame - Working With Specific Gestures for Different Purposes

Tags: c#, mobile, input, touch, monogame

Part of my particular dilemma is that I would like to be able to get the initial position of a drag gesture. Depending on the initial position of that drag gesture, the application would either 1) pan the view or 2) display a menu, but not perform these gestures at the same time (which is where part of struggle lies).

For example, if the user initiated a drag from the very left side of their screen and dragged inwards, a menu would pop in instead of the view panning.

I would also like to be able to execute a double tap gesture without also activating a tap gesture, if that's at all possible. I've tried working with boolean flags - for example,

```
// ...
if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.DoubleTap)
{
    isDoubleTap == true;
}

// ...
public static Vector2 Tap
{
    get
    {
        if (!isDoubleTap)
            return gesture.Position;
        // ...
```

But that doesn't work.

I've tried using TouchCollection - if anyone would like me to elaborate on my issues with that I can, but for now I'll say what I tried hasn't worked. It's entirely possible I may have just goofed as I am a novice when it comes to working with touch input.

I've been working on this for a few days and have done as much searching as I can, and nothing I've found has alleviated my issue - if I happened to have missed something, I apologize.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What about GestureType? Have you tried that? It has support for double tap.

Comment: GestureType works, but:

"[...] the application would either 1) pan the view or 2) display a menu, but not perform these gestures at the same time (which is where part of struggle lies)."

It performs the actions together.

Comment: You mean, it detected the gesture as a single tap, as opposed to double tap?

Comment: It detected a single tap and a double tap (the first tap of the double tap being the tap, and the quick second tap being the double tap).

Comment: The only way I can think of is by delaying whatever action it is Tap supposed to do. I'll post it as an answer if you want. However, if your game needs the tap action to be executed immediately, then this would be a problem.

Comment: It does, unfortunately. There may be no solution; something I just thought of that I may dabble into is using more than one finger for double tap.

Unfortunately, that still leaves me with the issue of finding a proper way to get dragging to work, though.

I appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Concerning start position of a drag:

There is a gesture for a drag ending, so if you receive a drag and its the first one since the last drag ended, thats the initial position.

Concerning tap/doubletap:

MonoGame works the same way as XNA as [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.touch.gesturetype.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> The user tapped the screen twice in quick succession. This
>   always is preceded by a Tap gesture.

This sounds like a input-bindings design problem more than a technical question imo. Consider also what you can move to instead occur on press or release rather than only making use of gestures.